# Checking domain for function to be 1-1.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Let $f:\Bbb R-\{0\} \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x^3}$. On which intervals is $f$ one-one?
$a)(-\infty,-1)$
 $b)(0,1)$.
 $c)(0,2)$.
  $d)(0,\infty)$.

I know that this is very basic question but I am not getting how to check domain for this function? Only I can say that f is odd function and hence it is symmetric with respect to origin.By checking it's kernel and to get nullity zero ,$x^2=-1$ which not possible for real numbers.Then how to check function's domain for f to be 1-1?

Comment: Find the turning points of $f$. $\frac{df}{dx}=1-\frac{3}{x^4}$. So the function has turning points at $x=\pm3^{1/4}$. The only one that does not contain that turning point is (b) as $3^{1/4}>1$.  (You should also check that the turning point is not a point of inflection.)

Comment: Just checking turning point is inside the domain or outside domain is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$f'(x)=1-\frac3{x^4}=\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{x^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{\sqrt3}{x^2}\right)\implies f'(x)\ge0\iff1-\frac{\sqrt3}{x^2}\ge0\iff$$

$$\left(1-\frac{\sqrt[4]3}x\right)\left(1+\frac{\sqrt[4]3}x\right)\ge0\stackrel{\cdot x^2}\iff\left(x-\sqrt[4]3\right)\left(x+\sqrt[4]3\right)\ge0\iff$$

$$x\le-\sqrt[4]3\;\;\text{or}\;\;x\ge\sqrt[4]3$$

and now you know *exactly* where your function is monotonic ascending (descending) and thus $\;1-1\;$ . Try to take it from here